# pre-order and "tree_insert" on a BST

Tags: binary-search-tree, preorder

if I have a BST (call it - T) and run PRE-ORDER on it,
how can I show/prove that running the function "tree_insert" on the sequence I got from the pre-order, I get exactly the same tree-T (I started with) back?

Thanks,

Comment: try here http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

For example, let's say you have 3 elements.

When you insert, the first element you insert will be taken as the root, then the next element(whether it is lower or larger) will placed accordingly to the left or right. Pre-order traversal means it will visit root first, then recursively visit the left child, then recursively visit the right child. So after pre-order will display root, the smaller element, and then the larger element. Now try inserting those 3 elements again. You will receive the same tree. (The first element inserted will be the root. Then the smaller element will again go to the left, and the larger element will automatically go to the right). You can model this with 6 different scenarios with 3 elements.

**Scenario 1**: Elements to insert = {1, 2, 3}
root = 1, right child = 2, right-most = 3

When doing preOrder, 1 is visited first. No left child so 2 is visited next. 2 has no left child so 3 is visited next. (1, 2, 3)

**Scenario 2**: Elements to insert = {2, 1, 3}
root = 2, left child = 1, right child = 3

When doing preOrder, 2 is visited first. Left child 1 so it's visited next. Right child is 3, so it's visited next. (2, 1, 3)

**Scenario 3**: Elements to insert = {3, 1, 2}
root = 3, left child = 1, right child of left child(with height of 1) = 2

When doing preOrder, 3 is visited first. Left child is 1 so it's visited next. No left child of 1, so 3 is visited next. (3, 1, 2)

There are 3 more scenarios which you can write out and check for yourself.

Comment: maybe the use of "show" (as in example) was not the best choice..
I guess i should use induction to prove this is correct for all cases, and the base step is obvious, but I'm not quite sure how to build my hypothesis...  (assume it is correct for all trees with height 1...n?)

Comment: Yes, you may do something like that. And breaking up into 6 cases would be my first approach, but I'm sure there is probably a more mathematically inclined way to do it using theory.

Answer (score 0):

For a given pre order traversal of a tree, there can be more than one BSTs formed. A unique BST can be generated if you have INORDER traversal too alongside the pre order traversal.

Comment: can you give me an example of an pre-order sequence that can generate more than one BST *when using insert_tree*?